# Monitor problems under windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, dell-xps, high-resolution, usb-c

I have an old Dell 3007WFP which only has DVI input. Previously, I was driving it via a mini-display port to display port chained to an active display port to dual link DVI converter, off a Dell XPS 15 (2014 model), which worked fine.

I was recently upgraded to the newer model of the XPS 15, which has a USB-C port rather than the mini-display port, so I purchased a usb-c to display port adaptor, which claimed to support 4Kx2K (sufficient) and which only had good reviews on Amazon.

For some reason though, plugging this in causes Windows to get stuck in an infinite loop. First, I hear the "new device plugged in" sound, then the laptop screen goes black, then the monitor standby light goes from orange to blue, then the laptop screen turns on again, and the monitor light goes back to orange.

The strange thing though, is that if I plug the monitor in immediately after clicking restart in windows, then the "Restarting" screen displays on the monitor, apparently at the correct resolution.

I have tried assorted fixes and workarounds, including:

1. Using EnTech's Monitor Asset Manager 2.9 to create a new INF file for the monitor, which I then installed.
2. Installing Dell's 3007WFP-HC drivers for Windows 7 (only ones available from Dell).
3. Setting a low resolution on the laptop's display prior to plugging in. (Plugging in seems to cause Windows to reset the laptop's display to native, so this doesn't help.)

Any ideas? The fact that it works on the "restart" screen suggests to me that there's nothing wrong with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Took me hours to resolve this, so posting for others in the hope they find it quicker. [From here](http://en.community.dell.com/owners-club/alienware/f/3746/t/19993880).

> The only resolutions officially supported on the 10 year old 3007WFP-HC are 1280x800 60Hz and 2560x1600 60Hz. But you must be using a DVI-D DL out port on the computer and DVI-D DL to DVI-D DL cable. Using HDMI, DP, or mDP outs from a computer with any combination of converters or cabling will not get 2560x1600 60Hz. They might get 1280x800 60Hz but Dell never tested them.

Comment: Not actually true. On the old Dell XPS we used a mini-DP to DP converter, plugged into a DP to DVI DL converter, and everything worked fine. (Of course we were using a DL cable.)
With the new Dell XPS we ended up buying the official Dell dock for the laptop, which also had a DP port. Using the same DP to DVI DL converter as before then worked fine. Though it doesn't explain why it didn't work with the USB-C to 4K DP converter.